# RxJava startsWith operator ignored when combined with observeOn

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a simple stream like that:

```
Observable.error<Int>(Exception()).startWith(1).subscribe {
        println("Item is $it")
    }
```

Everything is working like expected. First onNext is called with integer 1 and then exception is thrown, however when I change the stream by adding observeOn like that:

```
Observable.error<Int>(Exception()).startWith(1).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {
        println("Item is $it")
    }
```

onNext is never called. Only the exception is thrown. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the observeOn document

> Note that onError notifications will cut ahead of onNext notifications
>   on the emission thread if Scheduler is truly asynchronous.

That means when you apply it, the onError is emitted first & hence the onNext is not called as the streams has ended due to onError.

You can do the following in order to receive the onNext first

```
observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread(), true)
```

This tells the `Observable` to delay the error till the `onNext` of startWith is passed

Comment: Can anyone explain what is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Error conditions take precedence over data in the normal course of events. As Sandip explained, there are ways to change that using the standard operators.